# Windows 7 delete folder called 'prn'

Tags: windows-7, windows

Hi ya'll I have a folder on my desktop called 'prn' and when I try to delete it, I get this message "this is no longer located in C:\Users\username\Desktop Verify the item's location and try again."

I open my command prompt and tried to get to that folder and this message comes up 'The system cannot find the path specified'

How do I delete this folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PRN is a reserved name, so to delete you must use the **UNC**, (in **command prompt**)

`C:\>rd \\.\<drive letter>:\<dir>`

Example:

`rd \\.\c:\john\desktop\prn`

[ [::: source :::](https://web.archive.org/web/20140804174320/http://windowsitpro.com/windows/i-cant-delete-directory-called-con-prn) ]

Comment: Just a side note. I tried this in Powershell and it didn't work, but it did work in the good ol' command prompt.

Comment: Remember to enclose your path in quotes if any directories have spaces in their name.